# Get image from RestFul Web Service to Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: wcf, web, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have created a WCF service for my project and added image there successfully. You can check attached image *WebService.jpg* and *serviceImage.jpg*. I want to get that image on my Windows Phone 8.1 Project. Can anyone help how to do that ? How to read it ? I can successfully read JSON from my WP 8.1 project but dont know how to read image from service. Thank you

[image: This is how my service looks]

[image: This is image from my localhost]

Comment: How are you going to use the image in your Windows Phone app?

Comment: I want to add it to my flip view and get it from WCF service.